# sys.argv not working on sytems with previous .py associations

Tags: python, windows, command-line-arguments, sys

bit of background. I work for a VFX studio and we have in the past had to alter .py files for other programs just using notepad or notepad++, but no one ever actually used python.

So I have been rolling out python automation scripts now and they're working great, except one problem. Any machine who previously had python scripts associated with something other then python fail.

The script is called with an argument:

```
myScript.py <argument>
```

then I use:

```
print sys.argv
versionName = sys.argv[1]
```

This works great on all machines that never had python files associated with anything, however machines that had python previously associated with another application fail
it won't read the argument and i get a list index out or range error. 
The print line shows it is not recieving the input properly either.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Edit: Script returns this when run:

```
z:\pythonScripts>Make_version_1.py test
['Z:\\pythonscripts\\Make_Version_1.py']
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Z:\PythonScripts\Make_version_1.py", line 20, in <module>
        versionName = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list Out of range
```

This error is not returned form the majority of the machines in the office .. just ones where .py files had been associated with another program before python 2.7.6 was installed, so i know the code works.

Comment: How do you use it when associate the file with notepad++? double clicking? How do you pass args then?

Comment: Most likely, somebody manually set up the .py file association, and didn't consider command line args. If you re-install python on those machines, it should fix the problem for you.

Comment: Zhang - The .py files were previously associated with notepad++ not to run as scripts. Nuke uses .py files to pass default settings to the program through it's own internal python interpreter. Before i got here they just edited the .py files with notepad++. I'm passing arguments to them via command line as per normal usage

Markku - there was never a python install on them. Once Python was installed and i manually reassociate the .py files to python and it still dosnt' work

Comment: How did you manually re-associate python? On the command line, or in the registry? If you used the command line, did you do this: `assoc .py=PythonFile` and then `ftype PythonFile=python.exe %1 %*`?

Comment: i did it via right-click context menu in windows. The "choose default program" originally. I just redid it that way and i'm getting the same thing. The script runs, but the print line only prints the `sys.argv[0]` and then when i try to assign the variable it gives me a traceback error to that line and the error "Index Error: list index out of range". To reiterate, this script works perfectly on all machines who never had a previous .py extension

Comment: Can you also post the error output you are getting whenever you run the python command?

Comment: The standard approach on Windows I believe is to explicitly run `python script.py args ...` and not rely on associations.

Comment: Just wanted to share that i fixed the issue. Apparently preassociating a .py file breaks the setup of the windows path during installation. On my main machine i didn't need to adjust it, but i now have on all machines by adding `;c:\python27;c:\python27\scripts` to the environment variable. Now it works fine

Comment: You should post it as an answer, not a comment. However changing PATH should not change behavior when invoking scripts directly (not as an argument of the interpreter) in any case as this behavior comes only from registry settings and PATHEXT environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to share that i fixed the issue. Apparently preassociating a .py file breaks the setup of the windows path during installation. On my main machine i didn't need to adjust it, but i now have on all machines by adding `;c:\python27;c:\python27\scripts` to the environment variable. Now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Windows that you want to pass arguments to python. Open a command prompt, and do this:

```
assoc .py=PythonFile
ftype PythonFile=python.exe %1 %*
```

Comment: i did this, and it did not change the issue. I'm not having issues associating it. I'm having issues getting it to run properly. It might have nothing to do with previous file associations, it is just the common factor I'm finding.

Comment: What do you see if you type `assoc .py`? If it shows 'XXX', for example, then what do you see when you type `ftype XXX`?

Comment: when i do that i get `.py=Python.File` and `Python.File="c:\Python27\python.exe" %1 %*`. This matches the results from working machines. Editing initial post with actual error message